# How to decide the minimum browser version my website should support?

Tags: browser, frontend, browser-support

As a front-end developer, how should I realize what is the minimum version of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and etc that my web app should support? Should I consider all the users would use the last stable version? If not, how many older versions should be considered?

P.S. I faced this question wen I decided to use CSS grid display and my colleagues believed some users' browsers may not be updated to support this feature.

Comment: Start with finding out the distribution of browsers across all users: https://www.sitepoint.com/browsers-website-support/ ... then figure out what percentage of users for each browser use a certain minimum version.  If you can safely cover 99% of potential users, then maybe this is enough.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is figuring out what percentage of users for each browser use a certain minimum version ... @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Look here: https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php

Comment: You should actually use analytics and make a fundamented decision with your actual user base (maybe you have some stats globally or at country level but your actual user base is completelly different, don't base your decision on some generic data). Anyway, I don't think that just dropping grids is a good idea (+85% support globally is pretty good!), you could have some CSS for browsers that support grids and a fallback for browsers that does not support it. Check the `@support` feature queries https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8uxmUQZsck. Grids are pretty awesome, it's a shame not to use it.